# Angular2 - No provider for TemplateRef (ng2-bootstrap)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, ng2-bootstrap

I have been trying several solutios for this error, but didn't find any succesful way to overcome this: **No provider for TemplateRef!**

**Error log:**

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./FooterComponent
>   class FooterComponent - inline template:15:20 caused by: No provider
>   for TemplateRef! Error: Error in ./FooterComponent class
>   FooterComponent - inline template:15:20 caused by: No provider for
>   TemplateRef!
>
> Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in ./FooterComponent class
>   FooterComponent - inline template:15:20 caused by: No provider for
>   TemplateRef! ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:

**footer.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'sa-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html'
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

**footer.component.html**

```
<div class="page-footer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <span class="txt-color-white">myAPP © 2016</span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 text-right hidden-xs">
            <div class="txt-color-white inline-block">
                <i class="txt-color-blueLight hidden-mobile">Last account activity <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                    <strong>52 mins ago &nbsp;</strong> </i>

                <div class="btn-group dropup" dropdown>
                    <button class="btn btn-xs dropdown-toggle bg-color-blue txt-color-white" dropdownToggle>
                        <i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right text-left" dropdownMenu>
                        <li>
                            <div class="padding-5">
                                <p class="txt-color-darken font-sm no-margin">Download Progress</p>

                                <div class="progress progress-micro no-margin">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 50%;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="padding-5">
                                <p class="txt-color-darken font-sm no-margin">Server Load</p>

                                <div class="progress progress-micro no-margin">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 20%;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="padding-5">
                                <p class="txt-color-darken font-sm no-margin">Memory Load <span class="text-danger">*critical*</span>
                                </p>

                                <div class="progress progress-micro no-margin">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 70%;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="padding-5">
                                <button class="btn btn-block btn-default">refresh</button>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I tried to do the following:**

1. *Research*: 
   But only found answers / solutions for templates that actually contain some directives like `ngIf`, `ngSwitch`, etc. (Forgetting the `*`, for example)
2. Add `TemplateRef` to `providers`. This is what I get:

> Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; providers:
>   typeof TemplateRef[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'Component'.   Types of property 'providers' are incompatible.
>       Type 'typeof TemplateRef[]' is not assignable to type 'Provider[]'.
>         Type 'typeof TemplateRef' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
>           Type 'typeof TemplateRef' is not assignable to type 'FactoryProvider'.
>             Property 'provide' is missing in type 'typeof TemplateRef'.

I will try to see how to add somehow `TemplateRef` to the app's module `providers`. But I don't know if this is the solution.
 I hope someone comes out with a solution while I continue researching.

Thank you! :D

Comment: By the way. If you need clarifications, or better explaining or anything just let me know. Sorry beforehand if my explanation is not clear

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Research: But only found answers / solutions for templates that actually contain some directives like ngIf, ngSwitch, etc. (Forgetting the *, for example)

missing `*` here :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right text-left" dropdownMenu>
```

should be

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right text-left" *dropdownMenu>
```

From [ng2-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/dropdowns):

> ```
> <div class="btn-group" dropdown>
>   <button dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
>     Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
>   </button>
>   <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
>     <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
>     <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
>     <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
>     <li class="divider dropdown-divider"></li>
>     <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
>     </li>
>   </ul>
> </div>
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I actually found the issue and I addressed it like this: `bsDropdown=""` instead of `dropdownMenu`, and it works. The thing is that earlier this morning I updated `ng2-bootstrap`. But I didn't mention that on my OP. Anyways, with the information given by me, your solution is the correct one. I was looking for angular directives, forgot the bootstrap directive!

Comment: If you want, add also the `bsDropdown` option for updated `ng2-bootstrap`. I will change question name to relate it to bootstrap, so is more intuitive to find for people with the same issue. Thanks again!

Comment: @n00dl3 Big thanks, I've wasted almost half a day on this while updating a huge app from 2.4 > 4.0. Strangely, the error appears now but wasn't output before..