# No Provider for TemplateRef! (ng2 bootstrap)

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng2-bootstrap

I am using ng2 bootstrap and updated angular cli 1.0 version after that  got above error here is my code. could you plz solve this problem

☰

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" dropdown (onToggle)="toggled($event)">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
            dropdownToggle>
            <i class="icon-bell"></i> <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">5</span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" dropdownMenu aria-labelledby="simple-dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> You have 4 videos to Validate</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> Need to Declare winners for week 34</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" dropdown (onToggle)="toggled($event)">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
            dropdownToggle>
            <img src="assets/img/avatars/6.jpg" class="img-avatar" alt="admin@tfc.com">
            <span class="hidden-md-down">Super Admin</span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" dropdownMenu aria-labelledby="simple-dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-key"></i> Change Password</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Logout</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43114306/angular2-no-provider-for-templateref-ng2-bootstrap BTW

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns) it looks like your missing the `*` on the `dropdownMenu`.  It should be

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" *dropdownMenu aria-labelledby="simple-dropdown">
```

So `*dropdownMenu` requires the `*`, but the `dropdown` directive does not.

Example from docs:

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown>
  <button dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
    Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: there are were a small breaking change in v1.6.0 described in changelog